# How to recreat the documents folder if it was deleted in ios6?

Tags: ios, updates, documents

all:

In my developed app,I wrongly delete the documents folder when user do some action.

But my app is in the App Store. How can i reproduce the documents folder in the next update version?

When updated to the next version, will the documents folder will be created by ios automatically?
Or I must recreate the folder in code? Can documents folder created by code?

==============================================

hi,all:

Thank you for you help.I find even if i delete the documents folder of the app, when updating  the app to the new version,iOS will creat the folder automatically.But if in the root folder of the app, there is a file with name "documents",the documents folder will not be created automatically(But only in jailbreaked mobile ,you can creat file in the root of the app).So this may be a bug of iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When updated to the next version, will the documents folder will be
>   created by ios automatically? Or I must recreate the folder in code?
>   Can documents folder created by code?

No, it will not be created automatically. You should create this folder:

```
- (void) createFolderDocumentIfNotExisted
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:basePath]){
    NSError *err;
    [fm createDirectoryAtPath:basePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&err];
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you ,I use the code to creat the documents folder correctly.But iOS will creat the documents folder when updating to the new version in most situation.

Answer (score 0):

set param 2 to YES .

```
 - (BOOL)createDirectoryAtURL:(NSURL *)url 
withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)createIntermediates 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)error NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0);
```